# How to fix the error 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Tags: python

I have run this code but i'm trying to store it into csv file but i got an error.

```
import pandas as pd
from blocklib import generate_candidate_blocks
from blocklib import generate_blocks
from blocklib.evaluation import assess_blocks_2party
dd = pd.read_csv('file path\\page.csv')

blocking_config = {
"type": "p-sig",
"version": 1,
"config": {
    "blocking-features": [1, 2],
#         "record-id-col": 0,
    "filter": {
        "type": "ratio",
        "max": 0.02,
        "min": 0.00,
    },
    "blocking-filter": {
        "type": "bloom filter",
        "number-hash-functions": 4,
        "bf-len": 2048,
    },
    "signatureSpecs": [
        [
             {"type": "characters-at", "config": {"pos": [0]}, "feature": 1},
             {"type": "characters-at", "config": {"pos": [0]}, "feature": 2},
        ],
        [
            {"type": "metaphone", "feature": 1},
            {"type": "metaphone", "feature": 2},
        ]
    ]
}
}

pp = dd.to_dict(orient='split')['data']
print("Example PII", pp[0])
block_obj = generate_candidate_blocks(pp, blocking_config)
print(block_obj.state)
list(block_obj.blocks.keys())[0]

ss = pd.read_csv('file path\\page2.csv')
hh = ss.to_dict(orient='split')['data']
block_obj2 = generate_candidate_blocks(hh, blocking_config)
print(block_obj2.state)
print(list(block_obj2.blocks.keys())[0])
print(list(block_obj2.blocks.values())[1])

filtered_blocks1, filtered_blocks2 = generate_blocks([block_obj, block_obj2], K=2)
print('page: {} out of {} blocks are in common'.format(len(filtered_blocks1), len(block_obj.blocks)))
print('page2:   {} out of {} blocks are in common'.format(len(filtered_blocks2), len(block_obj2.blocks)))
```

I have tried to use the function 'to_csv' but i gives an error

```
   filtered_blocks1.to_csv('file path\\file1.csv' , index = True)
```

The error is here:

```
    AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

The output is resulted by using two csv files. How to save the resulted output into csv file?

Comment: Convert this dictionary filtered_blocks1 to dataframe then you can write as csv. `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filtered_blocks1` is a dictionary. to use `to_csv` as

```
filtered_blocks1.to_csv('file path\\file1.csv' , index = True)
```

`filtered_blocks1` should be a dataframe. Refer [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

you should do something like:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(filtered_blocks1)
pd.to_csv('file path\\file1.csv' , index = True)
```

Comment: I have tried this command but it store all the data in just two rows: 


```dd = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([filtered_blocks3], orient='columns', dtype=None, columns=None)

dd.to_csv('file path\\file1.csv' , index = True) ```